# Diferentes tipo de datos , endpoint api rest laravel

Tags: laravel, api, rest, postman, certificado-ssl

Cree un servicio Api Rest básico en laravel 4.2(Esto porque el proyecto fue creado en esta versión), y las respuestas locales me envia el tipo de dato correspondiente(Int), pero al ejecutar los endpoint desde el servidor arriba, recibo los tipos de datos diferente(String) a local (Int), agradecería alguien que sepa el porque de esto, adjunto ejemplo, mil gracias.
[image: Prueba Servidor Online]
[image: Prueba local(Localhost)]

Comment: ¿Cuales son los headers que utilizas en uno y otro? En uno tienes 7 headers y en otro 8.

Comment: La diferencia es que en local me crea un header "Cookie", que se envia como valor un laravel_sesion=ey......etc